# Why add () at the end of an immediately-invoked function expression?

Tags: javascript, function

So I decided to "re-learn" JavaScript since I forgot quite a bit. I stumbled across the "immediately-invoked function expression".

I understood everything except the `()` at the end.

Example:

```js
!(function(){
    console.log("Works");
})() // <----
```

I noticed that **without** it, it didn't run. But with it, it worked.
Why does the `()` matter?

The other, similar questions I found did not have the same **exact** question, I also searched on the web, still nothing.

Comment: That's how you execute all functions: You put an argument list enclosed in `()` after the function.

Comment: If you had a named function, you would call it using `funcName()`, right? It's the same thing.

Comment: Thank you! This clears this up for me. Also, would you put anything in the last `()`?

Comment: If you want to pass any arguments to the IIFE, then sure, you can pass in parameters just like any other function.

Comment: This is because we want to make it what it stands for i.e. "Immediately Invoked" - when the interpreter sees the `( )` alongside the function, it executes it immediately, you can put anything in it and then you can receive that in the function body as: `(function(name) { console.log(name); })("Bob");` here, "Bob" gets passed to the `name` parameter.

Comment: It is due to the call operator ... `()` ... that a *function expression* can be referred to as an ***immediately invoked*** one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you execute any function is by putting an argument list enclosed in `()` after an expression that evaluates to the function.

With normal named functions, the expression is just the name of the function. An IIFE doesn't need a name, because it's just being used this once, so it's just an anonymous function expression.

But you still execute it the same way, by putting an argument list after the expression. Usually an IIFE doesn't need any actual arguments, so the argument list is empty.

```
(function() {
  console.log("Works!");
})();
```

is essentially the same as

```
function tempName() {
  console.log("Works!");
}
tempName();
```

except that it doesn't create the name `tempName`.

And if you left out the `()` at the end, it would be like writing just

```
tempName;
```

which is just a reference to the function, it doesn't invoke it.